# Is it possible to create a responsive icon from a bmp?

Tags: html, responsive-design, icons

I am new to responsive design. However I have some BMP icons and wondered whether it is possible to create scalable/responsive icons from them. What would the format be? I did try SVG, but the browser does not do anything with these it seems.

Many thanks.

Comment: BMP is an array of pixels; you can't magically get a vector image from it. Also, what do you mean "the browser does not do anything with these"? That doesn't make much sense...

Comment: I clicked on the SVG, and the default program was IE. No image was shown although the XML could be seen via "Page Source". I did actually convert the BMP to a SVG via an online tool called cloudconvert: https://cloudconvert.org/bmp-to-svg. It did the job, however not sure what the output will be like. On further research I need to use the embed tag and then all modern browsers should display the SVG. However I am not sure this will create a responsive icon, ie one that minimises when the browser is minimised.

Comment: http://webstandardssherpa.com/reviews/responsive-webfont-icons/ was suggested as a solution by Dhanith, and it is useful. Sadly the answer has been deleted, so I am commenting on it for the benefit of all.

Comment: Yes, it was deleted, because it was a link-only answer, which is discouraged (and possibly spam). I flagged and downvoted it and [Bill the Lizard♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) deleted it. It is a good *comment* though, just not an *answer*.